# Linux installation on a chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook C7. Intel processor. I am somewhat familiar with basic coding in the terminal and all that. I am not thrilled with Chrome OS, so I'd like a nice linux desktop/OS that I can run on it instead. A full OS would be great, but it would be nice if I could test out different options first. Regardless, I have looked everywhere and tried downloading a ton of different links and codes, installing to usb boot, etc. But I can't seem to get a recent Ubuntu with applications, internet, etc. Permissions or not being able to find the source or something always stops me from getting any release. How can I do it?

Comment: You have a choice of installing either Chrubuntu or Crouton. Chrubuntu is stock Ubuntu, however Crouton runs better on Chromebooks in the opinion of many people. Googling "Chrubuntu vs. Crouton" will tell you both sides of the story.

Answer (score 0):

You can test out different options best by using crouton -- you can easily uninstall it by powerwashing your chromebook so it's a rather low-risk option (provided you back up your data!).

You can install quite a few versions of ubuntu and have a nice choice of DEs (unity, xfce, kde etc--you can even install cinnamon if you're willing to go the extra mile).

You can also create multiple chroots and delete the ones you don't like! You can then decide if you want to go with chrubuntu or stick with crouton! In my experience crouton runs better than I thought it would and booting into ChromeOS first hasn't really been much of a hassle.

There's an extra option, GalliumOS (look up the wiki) that's a bit more complicated to install depending on the model of your chromebook. Exercise **extra** caution if you choose to follow this approach.

[Here's the 2016 guide to installing crouton.](http://www.androidauthority.com/crouton-turn-your-chromebook-into-far-more-than-a-glorified-web-browser-663044/)